# How can I extract data from database sheet and paste matched range in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in a workbook. I wan't to copy cells containing SPT values for each Boreholes from the "combine" sheet based on sheetname matching within range listed within "A5:A116" or may be more after final data entry to the sheet matching with the borehole ID /cell value within range "A5:A116" and paste it below the SPT column. This has to continue through a loop process for all the sheets. Also a relative referencing from the matched cell to the range to be copied will be required. In the code the range D5:D16 will have to be a floating ranged based on relative referencing from cell value. Also the paste range will start from 1 cell below the SPT value in the matched.name sheet The code I am working on is as follows the relative referencing for range does not seem to work:

```
 Sub example()

 Dim wkSht As Worksheet

  For Each wkSht In Sheets

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A5:A116")

        If Cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then

            On Error Resume Next

            Sheets("Combine").Range("D5:D16").Copy Destination:=wkSht.Range("D29:D52")
        End If

    Next Cell

 Next wkSht

End Sub
```

Data Extraction in different sheets

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sequence for the looping is incorrect, and you did not declare the variable for `cell`, please try the following code modification and it shall work properly:

```
Sub example()

Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A5:A116").Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
       
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 11), cell.Offset(30, 11)).Copy wkSht.Range("D29")
        End If
    
    Next wkSht

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: instead of fixing the range to D5:D16 I wan' a relative reference of  = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Range(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(11, 0)).Address(False)).Select ... for copy having an offset from matched sheetname within range ("A5:A116")

Comment: See my edited answer for dynamic range copy paste, is it same as your expected output?

Comment: Solve This:Sub SPT()
Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A5:A116").Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
        cell.Select
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11), ActiveCell.Offset(30, 11)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wkSht.Select
        Range("D29").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
              
      Next wkSht
  Next cell
End Sub

Comment: Did you update your code? The sequence for the looping is wrong already...

Comment: Can you give me your email so, that I can share the excel

Comment: Why are we getting 1 and 2 values in sheet 2 , we are only supposed to get 2 and in case of sheet 4 we are supposed to get the value 3 and 4

Comment: Your copy paste method does not seem follow a certain rule?

Comment: It can follow a rule. from cell A (which matches with the sheet name) we can do a relative referencing for copying 30 columns : Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11), ActiveCell.Offset(30, 11)).Select and paste selected data in matched sheet name in cell "D29" and loop through all the cells in range and whenever the cell value matches with any of the sheet range it will do a relative referencing and copy 30 data and paste it in the matched sheet name by looping through all the sheets. I have updated the code but, still there is some problem [link] https://ibb.co/tshCg5b

Comment: I have amended my answer based on your new code, please run and see if working, avoid using `select` method in most case

Comment: Grt work. Now how can I make the cell.offset(0,11) ,cell.offset(30,11) dynamic. There may be 30 or 20 or any other number of data in the entry. The code will match the sheetname in range (A5:A116) and whenever, the range value changes to another name it will stop the row offset range and copy data based on that selection

Comment: Definitely it can be fixed, but you number for offsetting is referring to what value? Maybe you can open new thread and simplified your issue. There is alot people is willing to help and be more specific since you know the issue now :)

Comment: Sub Data_Click()

Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A4:A600").Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
       
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 13), cell.Offset(30, 13)).Copy wkSht.Range("B17")
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 18), cell.Offset(30, 18)).Copy wkSht.Range("017")
        End If
    
    Next wkSht

Next cell

End Sub 2nd Range is not working why?

Comment: You may try post your issue in a new tread as it is hard to read the issue from here :)